# Jquery url regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to make navigation on click.

Structure of the site is simple:

```
site.com/page_2/
site.com/page_3/
...
site.com/page_n/
```

How to get the URL of the page number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
> 'site.com/page_123/'.match(/page_(\d+)/)[1];
"123"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"site.com/page_123/".match(/(?:page_)(\d+)/)[1];
```

Comment: `?:` is not really needed. `/page_(\d+)/` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Or why complicate things with regex when you can substring as well:

```
"site.com/page_2/".substring("mysite.com/page_".length, name.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = window.location.href;
var x = s.split("/");
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(i==x.length-2) {
        var c = x[i].match(/page_(\d+)/)[1];
    }
}
```

Automatically gets the Page Number ;)
    ​
[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dy2bR/)

Comment: Why use a loop when you're going to act only once in a known index? Why not just `x[ x.length - 2 ].match(/page_(\d+)/)[1];`?

Comment: oh yeah thats the point but still gives what he want! @Juhana thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One more non regex solution:

```
parseInt("site.com/page_123/".split("page_").pop(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

find the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/N2WRS/

```
var url      = "http://www.site.com/page_2/"; // window.location
var nurl     = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));
var finalUrl = nurl.substr(nurl.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

alert(finalUrl); // <---this will get you the page_2
```